# How do I use GPU acceleration in FFMPEG when I want to generate mp4 file from jpg files?

Tags: ffmpeg

As title says, I have multiple `jpg` files and I would like to generate a `mp4` movie file using the FFMPEG. But, just using a CPU is taking too long. Is there a way to somehow use a GPU so that it would take shorter time to generate the `mp4` file?

I do not own a NVIDIA GPU, by the way, I would like to use a method that is more 'generic' for any kind of GPUs.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Here is the `ffmpeg` command that I am using

```
ffmpeg -start_number 2000 -i somepics.%5d.jpg -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" -pix_fmt yuv420p  somemovie.mp4
```

Comment: A question for [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com) perhaps? In any case, you should show the `ffmpeg` command line you are currently using, there may be possible improvements other than using GPU acceleration.

Comment: Video Production doesn't get that much attention: [su] is better. There is no generic method for any type of GPU. You'll need to tell us what hardware you have to get a specific answer. Or take a look at [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware Acceleration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro). Alternatively, if you are encoding with libx264 just use a faster `-preset`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using AMD GPU.

Comment: @Redshoe What is your OS?

Comment: I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: @Redshoe See [FFmpeg Wiki: VAAPI](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. My OS is Arch Linux.